# appcmd.exe 'set' and 'list' commands for service authentication issue

Tags: appcmd

Sorry about the non-descriptive title; Had no Idea how to put it. So when I run the following code in command prompt

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config "Default Web Site/Local\Service" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /clr:4
```

I get a snippet of xml back which includes

```
<WindowsAuthentication enabled="false authPersistNonNTLM="true">
```

I want to enable windows authentication for this service so I then run

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/Local/service" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /enabled:"True" /commit:apphost
```

If I rerun the orignal list command it is still returning that the windowsAuthentication  enabled state is false. The set command is working correctly and enabling/disabling the windowsAuthentication which I check by going into IIS Manager. I figured the set and list should be modifying or returing the same value. I need to get the list working (or some other similar command) because I need to check the state of the authentication for my services. So the question is am I missing something? Why do the set and list appear to be working of two different values, and how can I get this command (or a similar command) to return the enable state for a services authentication that I see in IIS Manager?

I'm running IIS 7 by the way. Not sure if that makes a difference or not. Sorry if I've left out any other required details. Not that familiar with IIS.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appcmd tool is sensitive to slashes.

In the `list` option, make sure you only use forward slashes otherwise the information returned will be from the first matching default and not the location you asked for.

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config "Default Web Site/Local/Service" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /clr:4
```